# Как настроить плагин чтоб уведомлял только при ошибках?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, sass

Как настроить notify чтобы уведомления появлялись только при ошибках?

"gulp-notify": "^3.0.0" - установлен
notify = require("gulp-notify") - подключен

Что в этот таск прописать?

```js
gulp.task('sass', function(){ // Создаем таск "sass"
    return gulp.src(['app/sass/*.sass',
                     'app/libs/libs.sass']) // Берем источник
        .pipe(sass({
          includePaths: bourbon.includePaths
          }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')) // Выгружаем результата в папку app/css
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true})) // Обновляем CSS на странице при изменении
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src(['app/sass/*.sass',
                 'app/libs/libs.sass'])
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: notify.onError("Error: <%= error.message %>")}))
        .pipe(sass({
          includePaths: bourbon.includePaths
          }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
    ;
});
```

Comment: Перестало выбивать из галпа при ошибках, но саму ошибку не пишет